# how can i avoid no reverse match in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I don't know why this error `occurred no revers match` while I'm practicing Django.

I modified the shops.html code to link pizza but after this modifying, this error occurred

> Reverse for 'pizza' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shops/(?P<pizza_id>[0-9]+)$']

first code :

```
<ul>
    {%for shop in shops%}

         <li>
            {{shop}}
         </li>
```

second code:

```
<ul>
    {%for shop in shops%}

     <li>
        <a href="{% url 'pizzas:pizza' pizza.id %}">{{shop}}</a></li>
```

I have Posted all codes in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/u/Nicolas_Darksoul/1/KUBPPDTG) if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that instead of `shop.pk` you used `pizza.id` and that is not actually defined.
change this

```
{%for shop in shops%}
 
 <li>
    <a href="{% url 'pizzas:pizza' pizza.id %}">{{shop}}</a></li>
 
{%empty%}
 
 <li>currently there is no pizza available</li>
{%endfor%}
```

to

```
{%for shop in shops%}
 
 <li>
    <a href="{% url 'pizzas:pizza' shop.pk %}">{{shop}}</a></li>
 
{%empty%}
 
 <li>currently there is no pizza available</li>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: idk whats this pk and why do we use shop can u a little explain?

Comment: @Nicolas_Darksoul pk stands for `primary key` instead of this you can use `id`.

Comment: @Nicolas_Darksoul does this solve your problem ?

Comment: yeah i got whats pk but im a little confused(its my first code) shop is the shop in dictionary means Pizza.objects.order_by("date_added") so how shop.id works and why dont we use id with pizza in pizza ,btw how do we use shop while we write url 'pizzas:pizza'

Comment: @Nicolas_Darksoul the problem is that you are using `shop` as varible to iterate over your `queryset` then how can you use an other variable that is not defined(`pizza`) if you want to pizza to work then change that variable to `pizza` that is it.something `{% for pizza in shops %}....{% endfor %}` with this you can use `pizza.id`

Comment: names is simillar in the book now i misunderstood thanks for help now i get it , sorry i ask you its not related to question but can you tell me how can i get used to django codes

Comment: @ nicolas_darksoul Just by doing good projects and answering questions  here in stackoverflow will help you a lot.do not forget to accept the answer.